# Connecting two android devices without a router

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, wifi-direct

myself and a friend want to play a multiplayer game that only works on the local network, and in work, there is no open WiFi network that we can both connect. Is there anyway that we can link up both our phones with wifi to play the game, without an extra router?

Maybe if I open the portable hotspot, it would work?

Thanks

Comment: Portable hotspot should do it, through I haven't tried it for this specifically myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hosting a Hotspot is your way to go!

You can download an app from the Play Store such as FoxFi, to setup a WiFi network using one of the devices, and use the other to connect.

If you need to know IP specifics, FoxFi will provide you with information on connected devices, and their address on the network.

Be careful when using this method though, as the person hosting the hotspot will accumulate all of the data usage from both devices.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I guess I should have tried that first before asking this question, but in my head, I didn't think it would work!

To overcome the data usage problem, I just turned off mobile data when the tether was active

Comment: Glad to help. And have fun.